# How to get free/busy information of not shared appointment attendee in .net?

Tags: .net, outlook

How to get free/busy information of not shared appointment attendee in .net?

Could we get only shared calendar appointment?

```
Recipient oRecip = ons.CreateRecipient("xxxxxx");
            MAPIFolder usersCalendarFolder = ons.**GetSharedDefaultFolder**(oRecip, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean  you want the free/busy intimation of an appointment attendee? Or that you want to create an appointment n another attendee's calendar?

Comment: I want to know the free/busy intimation of an appointment attendee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Recipient.FreeBusy`. Or `AddressEntry.GetFreeBusy`

Answer (score 0):

```
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
        service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        service.Url = new Uri("https://xxxxxxxxx/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

        List<AttendeeInfo> attendees = new List<AttendeeInfo>();
        attendees.Add(new AttendeeInfo("xxxxxx"));

        GetUserAvailabilityResults results =
            service.GetUserAvailability(attendees,
                new TimeWindow(DateTime.Now.Date, DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(24)),
                AvailabilityData.FreeBusy);

        AttendeeAvailability myAvailablity = results.AttendeesAvailability.FirstOrDefault();

        if (myAvailablity != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(
                "You have {0} appointments/meetings in the next 24 hours",
                myAvailablity.CalendarEvents.Count));
        }
```